# Sending data to multiple clients

Tags: python

Im creating a simple Client-Server chat system. Im using TCP and Im aware that TCP is end-end. But Im trying to forward the data that I receive from one client to the next client in array. But in the following code, Im trying to send it to all the clients(and even that fails :D)
Here is my code:

```
from socket import *
from os import *
from threading import *
def multipleClients():

    all_clients = []
    conn, addr = s.accept()

    all_clients.append(conn)
    print "is connected :D :)", addr
    while True:
        data= conn.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        print "message is :", repr(data)
        for c in all_clients:
            c.send(data)





host='localhost'
port=12000
s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)

print "Server is Running :D :p "


for i in range (5):
    Thread(target=multipleClients).start()
```

Comment: your variable `all_clients` is local, and hence there is one (different) copy for each trhead. So in each copy there is a single `conn` socket in that list. You need to make that list global, but then you have to deal with the concurrent access to the same list from different trheads. Better to use a `Queue` instead.

Answer (score 0):

TCP is a streaming protocol. You probably need some kind of message-protocol. `recv` can receive up to 1024 bytes, which can be one message, part of a message or multiple messages at once.

Every thread has only one client, because you have only one `accept`. You probably want to work with `select` to manage multiple connections.